# add columns to a table based on core data readout in specific order

Tags: xcode, cocoa, core-data, nstableview

The situation:

there are two tables, a main table and a secondary table. the main table is connected to a core data database.
i have set up the core data and the main table just like i wanted it.. everything is working fine and i am happy about it.

now i have to add the columns to the second table. 
basically the second tableview has a single column (image & text table cell view). i would need to add a column for each row of the first tableview (the one conected with the core data's array controller) as a checkbox column, and the header of this column should have the value stored in arrangedobjects.header. but this is not it. these new columns should be in a specific order: ascending order, based on the arrangedobjects.order value from the first table.

this should be executed whenever i hit a update button on the interface.

so the questions are:

-how can i add columns to the second table view based on the number of rows of the first tableview?

-how can i order the columns based on the value stored in a column from the first tableview?

-how can i set the column to a checkboxcolumn programatically?

-how can i programmatically set the column header to a value stored in the arraycontroller?

example of the desired result:

TABLE 1 (connected to core data)

```
 somecolumn | header | order | somecolumn | somecolumn
 ------------------------------------------------------
 text        hd1       3       text         text
 text        hd3       1       text         text
 text        hd4       7       text         text
```

Structure of TABLE 2: (all checkbox columns except the first, column order based on "order" field of TABLE 1, column header based on "header" filed of TABLE 1)

```
 existingcolumn | hd3 | hd1 | hd4
```

again, PLEASE be as clear as possible.

thank you

Best regards

Igor

*I already made a similar question in the past, but this one has way more content in it, thats the reason why i am starting a new one. i searched the web and found no answer to this specific question. also please keep in mind that i am a newbie at objective-c/cocoa programming so please be clear in your answers.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-how can i add columns to the second table view based on the number of rows of the first tableview?**

Create dynamic columns. you can use `[tableView addTableColumn];` inside loop for rows.count

**-how can i order the columns based on the value stored in a column from the first tableview?**

Order means...OrderBy? Sorted, You never sort a tableview, you sort the model array. Sort the array and populate the table.

**-how can i set the column to a checkboxcolumn programatically?**

For checkbox implementation, find a [project](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/5632433/table-checkboxtable-zip-2-5-meg?da=y) here.

Draw a checkBoxCell in the column you want to have checkbox. Or you can do it programatically.

I did it by IB.

You need to create an array that will store the states for each(number of rows) checkboxes.

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        states=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"0", @"1", nil];
    }
    return self; }



- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"Num of rows---- %ld", [names count]);
    return [names count];
}
```

Check for tableIdentifier having value "check".

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualTo:@"name"]) {
        return [names objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualTo:@"check"]) {

        return [states objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else if ([[tableColumn identifier] isEqualTo:@"states"]) {
        return [states objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Update the value of checkbox as per on/off.

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)value forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)column row:(NSInteger)row {          
    [states replaceObjectAtIndex:row withObject:value];
    [tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

**-how can i programmatically set the column header to a value stored in the arraycontroller?**

Use this category, or can use one line statement:

```
@interface NSTableColumn(SetTitle)

- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)inTitle
{
    [[self headerCell] setStringValue:inTitle] ;
    [[[self tableView] headerView] setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

@end
```

EDIT:

Checkbox programatically:

```
- (NSCell *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSButtonCell *cell=[[NSButtonCell alloc] init];
    NSString *strDisplayPlaylistName;
    strDisplayPlaylistName=[playListNameArray objectAtIndex:row];
    [cell setTitle:strDisplayPlaylistName];
    [cell setAllowsMixedState:YES];
    [cell setButtonType:NSSwitchButton];
    return cell; 
}


- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView setObjectValue:(id)anObject forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {          
    NSCell *aCell = [aTableColumn dataCellForRow:rowIndex];
    [aCell setNextState];
    //NSCell *aCell=[aAddedCells objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
    //[aCell setNextState];
}
```

Comment: thanks, but your answer covers only the checkbox managing part of the question. not the adding of the columns based on teh coredata readout, the adding of the checkboxes programmatically, order the columns based on the readout? thanks!

Comment: updated, but not sure about correctness... it too long, and i cant compile check, atleast you will get some idea

Comment: hello! thanks for your answer! by order i mean that i can specify with a numeric value the order or the column. (see example in first post) by "set a checkboxcolumn programmatically" i do not mean to set the check on/off. i mean that if i add a column programmatically (addTableColumn) then i have a textbox column. i have to change this programmatically to a checkboxcolumn. sorry if this was not clear! thanks!

Comment: You want checkbox programatically?

Comment: you wrote: "Draw a checkBoxCell in the column you want to have checkbox. Or you can do it programatically. 

I did it by IB."  what i need is to do it programmatically, not with IB.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23590/discussion-between-sharkyenergy-and-akv)